# Elasticsearch: Filter Query not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I've been working to change my query to a filter in Elasticsearch using the java api. I've made sure that the fields I am running searches on are set to "not_analzed".

Here is the java code for the filter:

```
FilterBuilder andFilter = FilterBuilders.andFilter(FilterBuilders.termFilter("thread_name", keyword), FilterBuilders.termFilter("site_name", "test_site"));

    QueryBuilder filteredQuery = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(), andFilter);

    SearchResponse threadResponse = client.prepareSearch("thread_and_messages").setQuery(filteredQuery).setSize(20).setFrom(firstRowOffset).execute().actionGet();
```

This then gets translated to this in JSON:

```
"filtered" : {
"query" : {
  "match_all" : { }
},
"filter" : {
  "and" : {
    "filters" : [ {
      "term" : {
        "thread_name" : "apple"
      }
    }, {
      "term" : {
        "site_name" : "test_site"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
}
```

When I try to do any searches it won't return the document I'm looking for which is thread_name: Apple and site_name: test_site.

Also when I run this using a curl command it won't find that document either.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you searching for `apple` or `Apple`. Please note the case.

Comment: Either, the thread_name field isn't analyzed so I assumed case wouldn't be an issue

Comment: That is the issue.. If it is not-analyzed. Case matters in `term query`. It looks for exact match.

Comment: So if I set it be analyzed this would sort out the issue?

Comment: On analyzed you will not be able to search for exact term. i.e . if  you have `red apple`. you won't be able to search for `red apple` using `term query`.

Comment: What type of query would you recommend in this circumstance?

Comment: Query_string would work there

Comment: Can I still use the 'And' function with this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `must clause`.That will perform `and` operation

```
 "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
           {
               "query_string": {
                  "default_field": "thread_name",
                  "query": "apple"
               }
           },
           {
               "query_string": {
                  "default_field": "site_name",
                  "query": "test_site"
               }

           }
        ]
    }
  }
```